# i want my element to change its size while spinning onclick of button

Tags: javascript, html

I want my element to change its size while spinning onclick of a button. i don't know why is not working but it is working correctly on: hover. below is the code for the same.
my HTML:

```
<div  class="rec">Rec</div>

<button id="button" >Spin me</button>
```

my CSS :

```
   html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   *, *::before, *::after {
         box-sizing: inherit;
   }

  .rec {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left:200px;
    transition: transform 1s ;


}
.play{
   
   transform: scale(2) rotate(360deg);
}

.rec:hover {
   transform: scale(2) rotate(360deg);
   transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}
```

my JS:

```
   var button = document.getElementById("button");
   var rect = document.querySelector(".rec");
   var play = document.querySelector('.play');

   function spin(){
        rect.classList.toggle('play');
    }
   button.onclick = spin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. This is your unedited example.

Maybe something else is blowing up that's preventing your onclick from getting set up? Forgot to save? Loading the wrong file?

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var rect = document.querySelector(".rec");
var play = document.querySelector('.play');

function spin() {
  rect.classList.toggle('play');
}
button.onclick = spin;
```

```css
.rec {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.play {
  transform: scale(2) rotate(360deg);
}

.rec:hover {
  transform: scale(2) rotate(360deg);
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="rec">Rec</div>

<button id="button">Spin me</button>
```

Comment: it is still not working for me but it is definitely working when i running the code snippet you added even working in the full window too. dont know what exactly causing the issue.

Comment: onclick is not working working me